# Soundcloud API not recognizing "Soundcloud Go" subscription

Tags: api, soundcloud, subscriptions

I just upgraded my account to the "Soundcloud Go" subscription and the API does not acknowledge the subscription:

Sample data from /Me endpoint

```
plan:"Free"
...
subscriptions:Array[0]
```

I gave it some time to refresh, I disconnected my account and re-connected it with a new access token with no different end result.

I was attempting to see if upgrading the account would allow greater access via the API as large portions of previously available data is now missing (for example I am only getting 42 of my "liked / favorited" items returned out of 62)